# Invalid url-pattern in web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web.xml

The web.xml for the [rssbus AS2 connector](http://www.rssbus.com/solutions/as2/download.aspx) web application uses the invalid url-pattern /**

```
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>Appuser Resource</web-resource-name>
  ...
  <url-pattern>/**</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
```

JBoss 6 throws a deployment exception:

```
 Deployment "vfs:///C:/Java/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/rssbus.war"
 is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
 1: URLPatternList item: /** matches: /*
```

Is this just a bug or does it work with some containers? The application file (war) is more than six months old and I can not imagine this has not been discovered (and fixed) yet.

Comment: Don't know if it works on some containers, but this kind of pattern is invalid, and doesn't respect the specifications. So I would say it's a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Just tried `/**` in a servlet filter definition in Glassfish Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5) and that didn't cause any warnings or errors.

Answer (score 0):

This was a url-pattern supported by Spring and other web servlet containers such as Jetty but has since been marked as a bug and fixed in the AS2 Connector.  You can download the latest version to run on JBoss.